# Custom indentation for long sentence when using bullet listing?

Tags: microsoft-word, bullets, indent

When a sentence is too long to fit on one line, the first word of the next line has the same indentation 'start point' as the line above it. I'd like the indentation or the start to begin 2 or 4 white spaces, to the right.

E.g.:

Instead of

```
{bullet symbol} Word1 - A sentence whose line 
                was too long
```

It would look like

```
{bullet symbol} Word1 - A sentence whose line 
                  was too long
```

For now, I have to resort to pressing the enter key, then deleting new bullet, then using the ruler tool at the software.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Left Indent of the paragraph so that it's where you want the subsequent lines to wrap, and place a tab at the original left indent location. For example, if the default for a bullet list is to indent by 0.25 inches (with a hanging indent of 0.25 inches), and you want to wrap at 0.5 inches except for the first line, you'd set the left indent to 0.5 inches, hanging indent 0.5 inches, and a tab stop at 0.25 inches.

Comment: Thanks. This is a screenshot, for others in case they have a bit of difficulty understanding it. Format painter seems to work with it. https://i.imgur.com/Pnak76y.jpg